# Generate CSS Pseudo content for before/after dynamically using Angularjs

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I have a div element and need to apply pseudo elements such as before and after dynamically. I will be pushing data to css "content" element dynamically from my scope. How can I do that using angular?

Sample CSS

```
    .bar:before {
  content: 'dynamic before text';
    height: 20px;
    }
.bar:after {
  content: 'dynamic after text';
    height: 20px;
}

<div class="bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use a custom `data` attribute for this to keep it flexible:

```css
.bar::before,
.bar::after
{
  background-color: silver;
}

.bar::before
{
  content: attr(data-before-content)
}

.bar::after
{
  content: attr(data-after-content)
}
```

```html
<div class="bar" data-before-content="Hello" data-after-content="There">I have content</div>
<div class="bar" data-before-content="Hello">I have content</div>
<div class="bar" data-after-content="Different">I have content</div>
<div class="bar">I have content only</div>
```

Comment: Cool. makes sense. let me try that. thnx!

Comment: You don't know how many hours I just spent trying to do something super specific in Angular 6. This plus attribute binding saved my life.

Answer (score 7):

You can use dynamic html-attributes for the content, like this:
JSBin: http://jsbin.com/sepino/edit?html,css,js,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        angular.module('test',[]).controller('testController',function(){
            this.textbefore = 'left ';
            this.textafter = ' right';
        });
    </script>
    <style>
    .bar:before {
        content:  attr(data-textbefore);
        height: 20px;
    }
    .bar:after {
        content:  attr(data-textafter);
        height: 20px;
    }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="testController as myCtrl">
    <div class="bar" data-textbefore="{{myCtrl.textbefore}}" data-textafter="{{myCtrl.textafter}}">inside</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thnx. that will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use attributes in the content field. I guess you could pull in what you need from that.

```
span:before {
   content: attr(data-content);
}
```

Comment: thnx! let me try that.