# Dynamically fill css Pseudo-element 'before' content with Angular2

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm having a hard time trying to dynamically fill the 'content'-value on a `:before` pseudo-element.
I've found out it was possible on earlier versions of AngularJS in another question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208926/generate-css-pseudo-content-for-before-after-dynamically-using-angularjs), by creating an extra data attribute on the element that has the `before`-pseudo element on it, and then read that value using `attr()` in CSS.

It seems to work just fine when using a plain string as a value:

```
// CSS
.test:before {
  content: attr(data-before);
}

// Template
<div class="test" data-before="before text goes here">
  <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
</div>
```

But when I try to fill the data-before with interpolation like this, I get an error:

```
// CSS
.test:before {
  content: attr(data-before);
}

// Template
<div class="test" data-before="{{name}}">
  <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
</div>
```

What am I missing here? The error generated is:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'before' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
```

Here's the non-working version in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/HwVp9jlsx6uKfoRduxWu

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use: `<div class="test" [attr.data-before]="[name]">`

**UPDATE**

You can also just drop the square brackets around `name` like this:

`<div ... [attr.data-before]="name">`.

This appears to be the convention in a number of examples I see. This works, I think, because you are already telling Angular to perform binding by specifying the `[attr.data-before]`, and it assumes the data on the right is coming from the corresponding component.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

For me, the below one worked in Angular version 8.

*HTML:*

```
<div style="display: block" class="testcl" [attr.data-before-content]="dynamicContent"></div>
```

*CSS:*

```
.testcl::before{
/* content: "56%"; */
content: attr(data-before-content);
position: absolute;
left: 46%;
top: 50%;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 24px;
color: #55b358;
```

}